# captures all stuff between the first " and the last "

Tags: regex, perl

I am looking for a regex which captures all stuff between the first " and the last " of a string than may contain further ".

```
$a='"xyz"kljhkljh"lkjhlkj"';
@b=$a=~ m/^"(.*)"$/m;
```

seems not to work?
There is no \n at the line end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second comment to tchrist's answer you say that the first and last quotes should be at the beginning and end of the string?  If that's the case, you don't even need a regular expression at all, just take the entire string minus the first and last characters:

```
    substr($a, 1, -1)
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason that yours is not working is that you are trying to restrict the first  quotation mark to occurring at the beginning of the string or immediately after a newline anywhere therein and the last quotation mark to occurring either at the end of the string or immediately before a newline anywhere therein.

That is not what your data contains.  Don’t make this harder than it need be.

If you want everything between the first double quote and the last one, including others, then you want

```
($content)  = $string =~ /"(.*)"/sx;
```

If you want lots of them, and no double quotes inside, you want:

```
(@contents) = $string =~ /"([^"]*)"/gx;
```

Comment: ($content)=$string=~/"(.*)"/sx works for me but what is the difference to $content=$string=~/"(.*)"/sx which does not work? @tchrist

Comment: restricting the occurence to start and end of the string is what I wanted. @tchrist

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I can't add a comment, so I'm creating an answer to answer bootware's comment on tchrist's answer.  The difference between `($content)=$string=~/"(.*)"/sx` and `$content=$string=~/"(.*)"/sx` is that the former matches in list context and the later in scalar context.  In scalar context the result is simply a 1 or 0 indicating whether the string matched the regex.  In list context, a list is returned for the substring that matched each parenthesized portion of the regex, in order from left to right.  In this case there was one set of parentheses in the regex, so the list returned had one element, the portion of the string that was inside the quotes.

Bonus:  You can refer to the substrings matched in each set of parenthesis using $1, $2, ...

Comment: You don't have enough reputation to put comments on every post.